# How to return a new object when the current object is recycled in Java

Tags: java, xpages, recycle, domino-designer-eclipse

In the following code the returned matchEntry is recycled, how can I fix that so that the returned matchEntry is not recycled.

I want the last matched entry in the loop to be returned

The object.clone() method does not seem to be available, and object.getClass().newInstance() doesn't seem to work.

```
public ViewEntry getStdTime(DateTime input,String key){
        
        ViewEntryCollection checkColl  = v.getAllEntriesByKey(key, true);
        ViewEntry checkEntry;
        ViewEntry checkTmpEntry = null;
        ViewEntry matchEntry = null;
                
        checkEntry = checkColl.getFirstEntry();
        while (checkEntry != null) {
            String xStartDate = checkEntry.getColumnValues().get(2);
            DateTime dtx = session.createDateTime(xStartDate); 
            if (dtx.toJavaDate().compareTo(input.toJavaDate()) <= 0) {
                matchEntry = checkEntry;
            }
            checkTmpEntry = checkColl.getNextEntry(checkEntry);
            checkEntry.recycle();
            checkEntry = checkTmpEntry;
        }
        return matchEntry;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean "recycled"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the entry as soon as you find it:

```
public ViewEntry getStdTime(DateTime input,String key){
    
    ViewEntryCollection checkColl  = v.getAllEntriesByKey(key, true);
    ViewEntry checkEntry;
    ViewEntry checkTmpEntry = null;
            
    checkEntry = checkColl.getFirstEntry();
    while (checkEntry != null) {
        String xStartDate = checkEntry.getColumnValues().get(2);
        DateTime dtx = session.createDateTime(xStartDate); 
        if (dtx.toJavaDate().compareTo(input.toJavaDate()) <= 0) {
            return checkEntry;
        }
        checkTmpEntry = checkColl.getNextEntry(checkEntry);
        checkEntry.recycle();
        checkEntry = checkTmpEntry;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Alternatively you can change your method to return the universal id of the document (using `checkEntry.getUniversalID()`) and then use that to get the document and the needed fields.

Comment: I want the last matched entry in the loop to be returned, I can maybe sort the collection descending and return the first entry. or use getLastEntry/getPrevEntry

Comment: Ah missed that part. I guess the issue is that you recycle checkEntry before returning matchEntry - and matchEntry points to the same object as checkEntry.

Comment: Perhaps you can use my answer if you reverse the sort order of the view 'v'.

Comment: I used getLastItem/getPrevItem to solve my problem and exit after the first I found.  sometimes it just helps to write the problem down. thx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a more elegant solution but this should do the job if I got it correctly:

```
public ViewEntry getStdTime(DateTime input,String key){
        
        ViewEntryCollection checkColl  = v.getAllEntriesByKey(key, true);
        ViewEntry checkEntry;
        ViewEntry checkTmpEntry = null;
        ViewEntry matchEntry = null;
                
        checkEntry = checkColl.getFirstEntry();
        while (checkEntry != null) {
            String xStartDate = checkEntry.getColumnValues().get(2);
            DateTime dtx = session.createDateTime(xStartDate); 
            if (dtx.toJavaDate().compareTo(input.toJavaDate()) <= 0) {
                if (matchEntry != null)
                  matchEntry.recycle();
                matchEntry = checkEntry;
            }
            checkTmpEntry = checkColl.getNextEntry(checkEntry);

            if (!checkEntry.equals(matchEntry))
              checkEntry.recycle();

            checkEntry = checkTmpEntry;
        }
        return matchEntry;
    }
```

The only non-recycled entry shoud be the last matched one